# How to reuse a newly assign column in a PostgreSQL update sentence

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-12

From this simple example it is clear that a newly assigned value of a column in an `update` sentence cannot simply be reused in other columns assignment.

```sql
drop table if exists stocks cascade;

create table stocks (
    id              serial,
    stock_available int,
    stock_locked    int
);

insert into stocks(stock_available, stock_locked) values 
(100, 10),
(100, 10),
(100, 10),
(100, 10),
(100, 10);

update stocks
set stock_available = 5, stock_locked = stock_available + 1;

select * from stocks;

id|stock_available|stock_locked|
--|---------------|------------|
 1|              5|         101|
 2|              5|         101|
 3|              5|         101|
 4|              5|         101|
 5|              5|         101|
```

What I am wondering if there is something like `excluded` for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "exclude" clause in the update statement. There is however an "include" clause: WHERE.  The WHERE clause defines the conditions which individual rows must satisfy. So for example:

```
update stocks
   set stock_available = 5
     , stock_locked = stock_available + 1  
 where id = 3;
```

You can effectively create a "exclude" by specifying a NOT condition within the WHERE. So (poor use a not condition, but it will demonstrate)

```
update stocks
   set stock_available = 7
     , stock_locked = stock_available + 1  
 where id NOT < 4;
```

The WHERE performs the exactly the same for select and delete statements. Namely to define the rows that qualify for the specified operation.

Comment: So it is as simple as `update stocks
set stock_available = 5, stock_locked = stock_available + 1
where id = id;`